# We were unable to deploy your project to your server (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, github, laravel-4, laravel-forge

I am working with a Laravel 4 project on Laravel Forge/AWS Ubuntu (Nginx server).  I have bene using auto-deploy, where all of my new code pushed to github is automatically deployed to the server by Forge.  However, a few days ago, I started getting the error:

```
We were unable to deploy your project to your server
```

On clicking the error, I get:

```
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

I've tried pushing the repo and github says all of my changes are up to date on the master branch.

What is the issue?

With this total output:

```
U   laravel/.gitignore
M   laravel/app/config/app.php
A   laravel/app/config/packages/abodeo/laravel-stripe/.gitkeep
A   laravel/app/config/packages/abodeo/laravel-stripe/stripe.php
U   laravel/app/controllers/FansController.php
M   laravel/app/database/migrations/2013_06_24_024946_create_fans_table.php
M   laravel/app/database/seeds/FansTableSeeder.php
M   laravel/app/models/Fan.php
U   laravel/app/models/Fanartist.php
M   laravel/app/views/artists/show.blade.php
D   laravel/app/views/fans/untitled
M   laravel/composer.json
M   laravel/public/assets/css/custom.css
A   laravel/public/assets/images/congruent_pentagon.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/diamond_upholstery.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/diamond_upholstery_@2X.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/escheresque.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/escheresque_@2X.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/foggy_birds.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/geometry.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/grey.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/grey_@2X.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/hexellence.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/hexellence_@2X.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/light_wool.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/light_wool_@2X.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/lightpaperfibers.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/paisley.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/psychedelic_pattern.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/psychedelic_pattern_@2X.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/redox_01.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/square_bg.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/strange_bullseyes.png
A   laravel/public/assets/images/strange_bullseyes_@2X.png
U   laravel/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php
U   laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
U   laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_files.php
U   laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php
U   laravel/vendor/composer/installed.json
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/.gitignore
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/README.md
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/bin/boris
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/box.json
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/composer.json
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/Boris.php
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/CLIOptionsHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/ColoredInspector.php
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/Config.php
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/DumpInspector.php
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/EvalWorker.php
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/ExportInspector.php
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/Inspector.php
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/ReadlineClient.php
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/Boris/ShallowParser.php
U   laravel/vendor/d11wtq/boris/lib/autoload.php
U   laravel/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/.travis.yml
U   laravel/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/README.md
U   laravel/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/ClosureParser.php
U   laravel/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/tests/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/Test/ClosureParserTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/madewithlove/laravel-oauth2/README.md
U   laravel/vendor/madewithlove/laravel-oauth2/src/OAuth2/Provider.php
U   laravel/vendor/madewithlove/laravel-oauth2/src/OAuth2/Provider/Facebook.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/CHANGELOG.mdown
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/README.mdown
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/composer.json
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/GelfMessageFormatter.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/HtmlFormatter.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/JsonFormatter.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/NormalizerFormatter.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/BrowserConsoleHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/FilterHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/FingersCrossedHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/HandlerInterface.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/HipChatHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/LogEntriesHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/MailHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/MandrillHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/NativeMailerHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/NewRelicHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/PushoverHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RavenHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/SlackHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/SwiftMailerHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/SyslogUdp/UdpSocket.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/SyslogUdpHandler.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Registry.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Formatter/GelfMessageFormatterTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatterTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Formatter/NormalizerFormatterTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Formatter/ScalarFormatterTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Handler/GelfHandlerLegacyTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Handler/HipChatHandlerTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Handler/NativeMailerHandlerTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Handler/NewRelicHandlerTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Handler/RavenHandlerTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Handler/SlackHandlerTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Handler/SyslogUdpHandlerTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Handler/UdpSocketTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/composer.json
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/readme.md
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/tests/AddTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/tests/ComparisonTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/tests/ConstructTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/tests/CreateFromTimestampTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/tests/DiffTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/tests/GettersTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/tests/SettersTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/tests/StringsTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/tests/TestFixture.php
U   laravel/vendor/nesbot/carbon/tests/TestingAidsTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/ollieread/multiauth/src/Ollieread/Multiauth/MultiManager.php
U   laravel/vendor/patchwork/utf8/CHANGELOG.md
U   laravel/vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/PHP/Shim/Mbstring.php
U   laravel/vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/PHP/Shim/charset/translit.ser
U   laravel/vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/PHP/Shim/unidata/canonicalComposition.ser
U   laravel/vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/PHP/Shim/unidata/canonicalDecomposition.ser
U   laravel/vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/PHP/Shim/unidata/combiningClass.ser
U   laravel/vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/PHP/Shim/unidata/compatibilityDecomposition.ser
U   laravel/vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/PHP/Shim/unidata/lowerCase.ser
U   laravel/vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/PHP/Shim/unidata/upperCase.ser
U   laravel/vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/Utf8/Bootup/iconv.php
U   laravel/vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/LoggerInterface.php
U   laravel/vendor/stack/builder/README.md
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/.gitattributes
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/CHANGES
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/VERSION
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/composer.json
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Events/SendEvent.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/FileSpool.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/ContentEncoder/Base64ContentEncoder.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMessage.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Signers/SMimeSigner.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/SpoolTransport.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swiftmailer_generate_mimes_config.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tests/_samples/smime/create-cert.sh
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tests/unit/Swift/MessageTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tests/unit/Swift/Mime/AbstractMimeEntityTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tests/unit/Swift/Mime/AttachmentTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tests/unit/Swift/Signers/SMimeSignerTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tests/unit/Swift/Transport/FailoverTransportTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tests/unit/Swift/Transport/LoadBalancedTransportTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/DependencyInjection/RegisterListenersPass.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Event.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventSubscriberInterface.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/GenericEvent.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ImmutableEventDispatcher.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/LICENSE
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/README.md
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Tests/ContainerAwareEventDispatcherTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Tests/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcherTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Tests/DependencyInjection/RegisterListenersPassTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Tests/EventTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Tests/GenericEventTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/composer.json
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/phpunit.xml.dist
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Exception/IOException.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/LICENSE
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/README.md
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Tests/FilesystemTest.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Tests/FilesystemTestCase.php
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/composer.json
U   laravel/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/phpunit.xml.dist
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
    Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
    as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have some local changes on your server side.

Try login via ssh to server and go to project repo location, then make:

git reset --hard

and redeploy